# Pure CSS Drop-Down Menu Doesn't Work on Firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I want it to like like this image (Works like this in Google Chrome, Opera, and Safari):

[image: http://imgur.com/RWpfX8m,QpAWmrx#0]

However, in Firefox and the latest version of IE, it looks like this:

[image: http://imgur.com/RWpfX8m,QpAWmrx#1]

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">OUR FACILITIES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">MEET THE STAFF</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">RESERVATIONS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">DIRECTIONS</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#navbar {
    margin-top: 87px;
}
#navbar ul {
    list-style: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
#navbar ul li {
    font-family: magic;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    background-color: #85CE85;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    padding-left: 45px;
    padding-right: 45px;
}
#navbar .selected {
    background-color: #CCFFCC;
}
#navbar ul li ul {
    display: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    width: 245px;
    height: 130px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: -85px;
    font-family: SkyHaven;
    font-size: .7em;
}
#navbar ul li:hover > ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
}
#navbar ul li ul li {
    width: 175px;
    border-top: 1px black dashed;
    background-color: #85CE85;
}
#navbar ul li ul li:hover {
    background-color: #6699FF;
}
#navbar ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#navbar a:hover {
    color: white;
    transition: .2s;
}
#navbar li:hover {
    background-color: #CC0000;
    transition: .8s;
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try using vendor prefixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the new code it will work for you with no problems:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpxaG/

As just and advice try to use html5shiv, to avoid IE problems:

[html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv)

Answer (score 1):

Changed this:

```
#navbar ul li:hover > ul {
display: block;
position: absolute;
}
```

Seems to be working for me in Firefox.  How does it look for you? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLw66/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/j22cG/

You need to position the submenu like so:

```
position:absolute;
top:100%;
left:0;
```

And position your parent li to relative.